# Is 'alias' a reserved word?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I'm using Angular 2 and Typescript. I've a component with a property declared like this.

```
alias: string;
```

When I try to bind this to a input tag in my template likte this.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required
                        [(ngModel)]="alias" ngControl="alias" #alias="ngForm" />
```

When running this code I get an error saying,

> angular2.dev.js:23925 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot
>   reassign a variable binding alias

If I change the property name from 'alias' to 'nameOrAlias' everything works as expected without errors. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Cannot reassign a variable binding alias ...

You get this error because you are trying to assign template variable with the same name `alias`:

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" required
       [(ngModel)]="alias" ngControl="alias" #alias="ngForm" />
                                             <!-- ^--- "alias" reasignment -->
```

So you should rename either template variable or component property.